# MySQL Inserting Unexepected Rows

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a Java/JPA/Hibernate application that has a MySQL backend.  Part of the database stores product data which is imported from a number of sources, so we have import records and import history records.  The import record says we imported some amount of products on this day from this source, and the import history connects the import to the products imported during that import.  This is because the product may appear in multiple imports, so this keeps a history of where it turned up and when.

```
purchased_product -< purchased_product_import_history >- import
```

Recently we have noticed something very strange when we create a new product record.  It creates a new product, import and import history as expected, but then creates *another* history entry that points to a completely different (already existing) import.  This bogus import record is always the same (always has ID 188).

- We assumed there is something in the code pointing to 188: no.
- We have debugged through the operation in the java code where a new product is created.  Only the correct import history is generated.
- The bogus association seems to be created immediately
- We have turned on SQL logging (hibernate SqlStatementLogger) and there is only a single insert statement and checking the values going in, it's showing the correct import ID, not the bogus one.
- There are no triggers or stored procedures in the database
- We have turned on the mysql log and looked through the whole logs during the addition of the product, and there is only 1 'insert into purchased_product_import_history' statement, and the value 188 is nowhere to be seen.

We are reasonably sure now it's not the Java code and something in MySQL is causing the insert, but are out of ideas for where this is coming from.  Can anyone help?

Java 8, MySQL 5.6.38

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the entities connected with "OneToMany"/"ManyToOne" associations? If yes, is there a CascadeType set?

Comment: Hi, yes PurchasedProductImportHistory -> PurchasedProduct has ManyToOne with no explicit cascades.  In the opposite direction it has OneToMany with PERSIST, REFRESH, REMOVE, DETACH and orphanRemoval=true.  PPIH -> Import has ManyToOne with no explicit cascade, and is not mapped in the other direction.

Comment: An additional test was to disable foreign key checks  in the database, then change the import record with ID 188 to have a different ID (99999), then re-enabled foreign key checks.  Added another product and exactly the same thing happened, only falling over when we tried to view the history for the new hardware.  No errors in MySQL error log, still used ID 188.

Comment: I believe the problem could be the PERSIST in the cascadeType, he is probably persisting a new entity everytime.

Comment: Hi, I removed the PERSIST from the cascade and tried to create another product record.  This just made it fail to create the correct import history association record, but the bogus association was still created!  The logs contained no insert into PPIH statement.  I'm pretty sure this is MySQL doing this but I cant work out why.

Comment: Removing will ofc make it fail, but if it still creates the bogus association, that means there must either be another CascadeType somewhere, or as you said, it's MySQL